# unwrapping an object returned from twitter api

Tags: ruby, twitter

While reading some data from the Twitter api, I inserted the data into the file like this

```
 results.each do |f|
        running_count += 1

        myfile.puts "#{f.user_mentions}"
        ...
```

The results (2 sample lines below) look like this in the file

```
[#<Twitter::Entity::UserMention:0x007fda754035803485 @attrs={:screen_name=>"mr_blah_blah", :name=>"mr blah blah", :id=>2142450461, :id_str=>"2141354324324", :indices=>[3, 15]}>]
[#<Twitter::Entity::UserMention:0x007f490580928 @attrs={:screen_name=>"andrew_jackson", :name=>"Andy Jackson", :id=>1607sdfds, :id_str=>"16345435", :indices=>[3, 14]}>]
```

Since the only information I'm actually interested in is the `:screen_name`, I was wondering if there's a way that I could only insert the screen names into the file. Since each line is in array brackets and then I'm looking for the screen name inside the `@attrs`, I did this

```
myfile.puts "#{f.user_mentions[0]@attrs{"screen_name"}}"
```

This didn't work, and I didn't expect it to, as I'm not really sure if that's technically array etc.  Can you suggest how it would be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the @attrs instance variable in the Twitter UserMention object. If you want to puts the screen name from the first object, based on your current output, I would write

`myfile.puts "#{f.user_mentions[0].attrs[:screen_name]"`

Also, putting the code on how results is returned would help get a definite answer quickly. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, how did you know to access `@attrs` with `.attrs`. Is that pure Ruby or something about Twitter api?

Comment: Twitter makes the attributes readable from the Twitter objects. In ruby, you can access the attributes by calling the method .attr because making it readable effectively creates a method in the class called `def attrs @attrs end` so you are calling the reader method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that results is an array of Twitter::Entity::UserMention

```
results.each do |r|
  myfile.puts r.screen_name
end
```